# will be any problem with my website if I empty all the cache tables from Database?

Tags: 7, database, caching

I'm trying to move my website from localhost to a server. the size of DB is too big and from what I saw the cache tables have big size. is there any problem (for my localhost version of site) if I empty all of them? (specially `cache_form`)

besides that when I was trying to import the DB into server the server reported an error when it was inserting `cache_views` table; it is very important for me to empty this table to avoid insertion error in the future.

thanks

Comment: I would recommend to either use the `drush`, or clear the cache from the `/admin/config/development/performance` page. However if do you some reason you are not able to clear the cache from this place than only you should go for manually clearing the cache tables

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal clearing the cache from `/performance` does not empty above mentioned tables. besides that I'm going to clear the cache table because of moving the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the drupal [community doc for clearing the cache](https://drupal.org/node/42055) you can manually TRUNCATE the tables (empty, not remove) starting with `cache_` and there shouldn't be any problem doing so as on visiting any page the cache is rebuilt.

However I would recommend to either use the drush, or clear the cache from the `/admin/config/development/performance` page.

If you want to clear the cache from code than you may try the following:

```
// clear cache
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

Also its always safe to keep the **Backup of database** before making any manual operation on database.

Comment: even though `clear cache` code didn't clear those tables (it is really surprising!) but from what you and Nigel said, it should be safe. thanks

Comment: @Mohammad It may be not emptying the tables as the cache gets rebuilt, so you can manually TRUNCATE the tables (empty, not remove) starting with cache_ and there shouldn't be any problem doing.

Comment: I did this and successfully imported DB to server, thanks

Comment: That page on DO is not 100% accurate.  `{cache_form}` isn't a true cache table.  Totally clearing it may cause problems for any in progress forms.

Comment: @MPD Yeah right, Thanks for mentioning this point :)

Comment: I'm opening a discussion on the D.O docs to correct this oversight.